# Sql Server Differential Backups Vary in Size

Tags: sql-server

I setup a SQL Server maintenance plan as follows:

- Full backup every Sunday at 2am
- Differential backup every 3 hours

After the full backup was taken, I noticed the differential backups are varying in size.  At first it started out small and grew accordingly.  However, at various points, some differential backup file sizes may be larger or smaller than before.  This includes big differences (i.e. 200MB to 3MB).  I know that no other full backups have been taken nor has any large amount of data been deleted during those times.  What would be the cause and is there something I am missing?  Based on the research I've done, the differential should do nothing but increase until another full backup is taken.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd test that these backups actually work... Maybe another full backup slipped an and those diff backups now help you nothing. Restore one of the anomalous backups.

Comment: That sounds very suspicious. Verify that there are no other backups running by looking at the bacupset table in msdb. I'd be that there's something like a VM backup or something like that running.

Comment: I went to this site: [link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1601/script-to-retrieve-sql-server-database-backup-history-and-no-backups/) and ran the first script.  It looks like a full backup occurred somehow.  I say somehow because the physical_device_name field contains a guid instead of actual physical paths.  Most of the rows in the result set actually have a path in that column and one that I am aware of.  Is it possible SQL Server is taking full backups on it's own?

Comment: I have exactly the same question, and I am also wondering why this happens (i.e. differential backup size varies since last full backup, and to me the diff bkup size should keep on growing until the next full backup)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about [differential backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175526(v=sql.105).aspx) or differential [partial backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191539(v=sql.105).aspx)?  What you describe looks a lot like differential partial backup.  Differential partial backup were introduced with MSSQL Server 2005 and are very similar to [incremental backup](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_backup).

With differential partial backups only the changes since the last partial differential backup are kept.  That means two things :

- the file size of differential partial backup will vary according to the amount of changes in the database since the last differential partial backup.
- if you want to restore a backup you have to restore the full partial backup (the base) and then every differential partial backup file.

Here is a very complete and interesting [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/backup-and-recovery/partial-backup-and-restore/) about MSSQL partial backup.

**Edit**

The terminology used is a little confusing.  In Microsoft documentation it is called *partial differential backup* (even though it works pretty much like an incremental backup) and to do that you have to use the very intuitive `READ_WRITE_FILEGROUPS` flag.  AFAIK, you have to use T-SQL commands like :

```
BACKUP DATABASE [SampleDB] READ_WRITE_FILEGROUPS
TO DISK = N'C:\SQLBackups\SampleDB_PARTIAL_Diff.bak'
WITH DIFFERENTIAL
GO
```

Comment: When I created the maintenance plan, I selected Backup Database (Differential).  Since I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, does it do Partial Differential backups by default when you select this option?

Comment: Probably not.  Do you have an other backup solution running?  Something like Backup Exec for instance?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  I've checked any extraneous jobs, but I don't see anything that resembles full backups

Comment: Are you sure that partial differential backups backup the changes since the last partial differential? They should backup the changes since the last partial.

Comment: @usr Missing word there.  I'll edit my answer but, obviously, it is not the answer to the OP problem.